# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation Error

Tags: python, indentation

I cannot run my very simple routine(in Python) because of the error mentioned above.  I have used only tabs and have deleted and retabbed the line, but to still no avail. I am using notepad++ as my editor and was wondering if there was something better I should be using.

Offending code is :
Sorting out being read books

```
for record in records:
    #print(record)
    if record[1]=="2":
        o=Label(midframe,text=str(record[1]))
        o.grid(row=(0+x), column=1, padx=5,pady=5)
        record.append(str(record[0]))
        ty.append(str(record[1]))
        desc.append(str((record[2])))
        pos.append(str((record[3])))
        x=x+1
        print(" Total Number of being read :", x)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I have used only tabs" - edit view shows that's clearly not the case.

Comment: Notepad++ should have a button somewhere to automatically convert indentation. Find it and hit it.

Comment: Supposing your orignal file is `foo.py` you could open the python shell and do `print(open("foo.py").read().replace("    ", "XXXX"))` - that's 4 spaces. if you see X's, you've got spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: More generally, style guides typically require using 4 spaces for indents and not using tabs. This is the reason. Its hard to spot errors. If you don't use tabs for indents but see the error, a quick search for the tab identifies the problem.

Comment: _have deleted and retabbed the line_ Which line? Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using Sublime Text. Select the snippet of code giving error and it will show  `--->` for tab and `......` for spaces.

Make sure for code at same indent level must have similar consistency i.e either use tabs or spaces butnot both.